# Is it possible to record live streams with ffmpeg in an audio file with embedded timestamps?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, recording, timestamp

I would like to record the daily programme of an IceCast radio channel (maybe a 24 hour stream), and then select my favourite programmes by embedded timestamps - if possible - according to the daily programme table.